Survival Analysis on different disease types with other covariates
I'm new to survival analysis but what would be the best way to make a cox regression if my dataset contains different types of cancer with many coviarates like age, sex etc. My dataset has no censored data - all patients are dead.
Seems like there's 2 ways I can go about it: make a cox regression for each types of cancer, or make the cancer type a 'covariate' but I'm not sure what model is better. My main goal is to fit a new observation that follows:
Breast cancer, age 39, female etc and plot out the survival plot using something like this code:
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time) ~ disease_type + Age + Sex, data =  data, model = TRUE)

fit <- survfit(cox_model, newdata)

plot(fit, ylab = "Probability of Survival",
     xlab = "Time", col = c("red", "black", "black"))

Any advice?
